# Intentionally reveal unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs)

Tags: transaction-data, confidential-transactions, blockchain-analysis, txo-set

As per [this discussion](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/is-there-a-way-to-view-and-or-calculate-the-value-of-all-utxos) I learned it is not possible in Monero to count the total unspent transaction outputs (UTXOs) in the blockchain to verify the total coin supply. I can understand that this is not even needed since the total coin supply can be verified during coin creation but I have something else on my mind.

I think of a possible blockchain application where I need to be able to destroy the oldest unspent coins in given intervals but I would like the best coin privacy possible. This means I need to be able to identify the oldest unspent transaction outputs. Could this be implemented somehow on top of current Monero privacy level?

I am afraid that what I need goes against the transaction untraceability/unlinkability of Monero because to see if an output was spend or not I need to see whether a given address is an input for transaction later in the blockchain. I just need to verify whether this is true.

Comment: Can you clarify? It sounds like you want to spend your own oldest outputs?

Comment: I want to have a dynamic monetary base which can both inflate and shrink. The inflation can be done by mining (which has been invented already and is in widespread use) but the shrinking of the monetary base (decreasing total coins in circulation) it the point here. The idea is to simply burn the oldest unspent coins no matter who these belong to. This would stimulate transactions in the network - people would "move" the unspent outputs from the back of the chain to its top.